Install Ubuntu on Apple Fusion Drive ( 24 GB NVME + 1 TB HDD )
I just bought a cheap iMac 2015 27" 5K ( iMac17,1 ) with an Apple Fusion Drive.
This drive has only 24 GB NVME and 1 TB HDD. I tried Ubuntu live (23.10), it works good (sometimes only the Bluetooth doesn't work but I must double check it).
When I start the installation I need to select the NVME or the HDD but I think the NVME is too small and the HDD is too slow.
What should I do?
How can I partition it in the best way?
Is there a simple way to make it work as on Mac OS (basically an hybrid disk)?
I read about bcache, but is it a good solution in this case?
I do not want to change the drive for a bigger full SSD because it is very difficult to open this PC (glue between the screen and the chassis) and I do not want to damage it.
And I do not need encryption or anything special, I just would like to easily install Ubuntu and use the PC with Firefox, Libreoffice and Steam.
Thank you all very much !!

During installation you can set up some folders like /usr, and /var in separate partitions in NVME, and everything else on the HDD.

I use Ubuntu on a 2014 iMac (HDD) with an i5 processor. While startup takes 1 minute, it is not that slow afterward.
